# Windows Phone 8: Play YouTube live event stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, youtube, windows-phone, video-streaming

Is there any way to play youtube live stream on Windows Phone 8 & C#?

1) I have tried [mytoolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/): it can play simple video but shows "no_video_urls_found" on live events.
2) Mobile IE shows "Live event playback is not supported on this client" so I cannot use browser to play it.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/user/HromadskeTV?feature=watch) is YouTube channel which contains live events I would like to play.

Is there any other way to play live stream with Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 7):

Besides Flash streaming, YouTube uses HLS. HLS is from Apple and means "HTTP Live Streaming". It's not standardized, but Apple tries to do so.

This means you need to find the URL and then can use any library which can decode HLS, e.g. [Windows Phone Streaming Media](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/) and then play the stream in a video player, where 2 examples are given at given the Codeplex site.